# Survival analysis using R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

On running a survival model using the survival package I encountered a strange error message which I am unable to understand.

The error message was

```
Error in Surv(time, event) : Time and status are different lengths
```

The number of observations in each column used in `model1` is exactly the same.

```
> mydata3<-read.csv(file.choose())
> attach(mydata3)
> event<-Event
> time<-time
> x<-cbind(WDCL,Age,SEX)
> ch<-coxph(Surv(time,event)~x,method="breslow")
```

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: without mydata3 it is really difficult to tell what the problem is

Comment: Don't attach your data, it's a terrible habit.

Comment: Stedy if you want I can mail you my data set.please send me your email address.

Comment: `coxph(Surv(time, Event) ~ WDCL + Age + SEX,method="breslow", data = mydata3)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the formula correctly, by adding all arguments.

Try this:

```
coxph(Surv(time, Event) ~ WDCL + Age + SEX, method="breslow", data = mydata3)
```